# how to edit move_base in turtlebot3 to not use dijkstra and use other algorithms like A* search or carrot planner

Tags: navigation, ros-melodic, move-base

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am new to ROS and I recently learned about the navigation stack and SLAM on turtlebot3. The regular navfn of turtlebot3 uses dijkstra algorithm. By simply setting the `use_dijkstra=false` the behavior of the global planner can be changed to use A* search instead.

I am having trouble finding the code or the file where I can actually make changes to the script and set `use_dijkstra` to `false`.

I'm not sure but i believe these changes must be made to `move_base.launch`

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/391318/how-to-edit-move_base-in-turtlebot3-to-not-use-dijkstra-and-use-other-algorithms-like-a*-search-or-carrot-planner/) by [Victor_Kash](https://answers.ros.org/users/71808/victor_kash/) on ROS Answers with karma: 50 on 2021-11-20

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

`global_planner` provides an implementation of a fast, interpolated global planner for navigation. This class adheres to the `nav_core::BaseGlobalPlanner` interface specified in the nav_core package.

`use_dijkstra` is one of the parameters of this global_planner

Reference: http://wiki.ros.org/global_planner

`move_base` is also part of Navigation stack but it provides an implementation of an action (see the actionlib package) that, given a goal in the world, will attempt to reach it with a mobile base. The move_base node links together a global and local planner to accomplish its global navigation task. It supports any **global planner** adhering to the `nav_core::BaseGlobalPlanner` interface.

Reference: http://wiki.ros.org/move_base

For turtlebot3 implementation, take a look at this example: https://github.com/NVIDIA-AI-IOT/turtlebot3/blob/master/turtlebot_apps/turtlebot_navigation/param/global_planner_params.yaml. Notice the initial parameters:

```
GlobalPlanner:                                  # Also see: http://wiki.ros.org/global_planner
  old_navfn_behavior: false                     # Exactly mirror behavior of navfn, use defaults for other boolean parameters, default false
  use_quadratic: true                           # Use the quadratic approximation of the potential. Otherwise, use a simpler calculation, default true
  use_dijkstra: true                            # Use dijkstra's algorithm. Otherwise, A*, default true
  use_grid_path: false                          # Create a path that follows the grid boundaries. Otherwise, use a gradient descent method, default false
```

And how the launch file calls for those parameters: https://github.com/NVIDIA-AI-IOT/turtlebot3/blob/master/turtlebot_apps/turtlebot_navigation/launch/includes/move_base.launch.xml

```
  <node pkg="move_base" type="move_base" respawn="false" name="move_base" output="screen">
    <rosparam file="$(find turtlebot_navigation)/param/costmap_common_params.yaml" command="load" ns="global_costmap" />
    <rosparam file="$(find turtlebot_navigation)/param/costmap_common_params.yaml" command="load" ns="local_costmap" />   
    <rosparam file="$(find turtlebot_navigation)/param/local_costmap_params.yaml" command="load" />   
    <rosparam file="$(find turtlebot_navigation)/param/global_costmap_params.yaml" command="load" />
    <rosparam file="$(find turtlebot_navigation)/param/dwa_local_planner_params.yaml" command="load" />
    <rosparam file="$(find turtlebot_navigation)/param/move_base_params.yaml" command="load" />
    <rosparam file="$(find turtlebot_navigation)/param/global_planner_params.yaml" command="load" />
    <rosparam file="$(find turtlebot_navigation)/param/navfn_global_planner_params.yaml" command="load" />
    <!-- external params file that could be loaded into the move_base namespace -->
    <rosparam file="$(arg custom_param_file)" command="load" />
```

---

Originally posted by [osilva](https://answers.ros.org/users/84086/osilva/) with karma: 1650 on 2021-11-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Mike Scheutzow](https://answers.ros.org/users/75154/mike-scheutzow/) on 2021-11-20**:
@Victor_Kash standard ros has multipe "global planner" implementations: two of the implementations are named `navfn` and `global_planner`. I believe that `navfn` does not implement the A* algorithm. So first you will need to change the move_base configuration to use `global_planner`, then you would change the `global_planner` configuration to use A*.

**Comment by [Victor_Kash](https://answers.ros.org/users/71808/victor_kash/) on 2021-11-21**:
thanks that works but upon setting `use_dijkstra` to `false` it shows it weird wall sticking behavior like this https://drive.google.com/file/d/1yr3Ejj22hQHmHARro1z8-mNVnteAgAgj/view?usp=sharing

**Comment by [osilva](https://answers.ros.org/users/84086/osilva/) on 2021-11-21**:
You will need to review some of your parameters. Dijkstra and A* are similar but not the same.

**Comment by [Victor_Kash](https://answers.ros.org/users/71808/victor_kash/) on 2021-11-25**:
yeah tweaking the neutral_cost seems to have solved the problem